# В чем заключается ошибка при переходе к контроллеру?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему с ошибкой, может кто сталкивался?
делал все по видеоуроку. при запуске приложения и добавлении в адресной строке FoodCart/Index, появляется необработанное исключение
`System.InvalidOperationException: "Session has not been configured for this application or request."`
в коде `ISession session = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.Session;`.

в `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` добавлено `services.AddMemoryCache(); services.AddSession();`

в `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` добавлено `app.UseSession();`

куда еще смотреть?

Comment: скиньте весь участвующий код, или лучше ссылку на проект с:

Comment: @Buka  https://github.com/nikitasalnikov/ASP.NET-CORE-MVC/tree/main/Vkusno_Doma

Answer (score 0):

к сессии можно получить доступ только во время запроса, и не совсем понятно зачем регать метод получения карточки в сервисах

Comment: "к сессии можно получить доступ только во время запроса" можете это объяснить. и как вообще решить проблему. делал по этому видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK8lO83OMRQ&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFWltIe7D6aUS5f4k1y2-rgn&index=15

Comment: @nikitasalnikov в основном сайты работают по принципу запрос-ответ, какие запросы отправляются можно посмотреть через f12 в хроме во вкладке Network. инфу об этих запросах содержит HttpContext. доступ к нему можно получить например в методах контроллера FoodCart/FoodCartIndex или Foods/List

Answer (score 0):

С **public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)** уберите **app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();** и напишите после **app.UseSession();**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

В итоге получится

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
        {
            AppDBContent content = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDBContent>();
            DBObjects.Initial(content);
        }


    }
```

Comment: теперь появляется другое необработанное исключение в том же классе но в последнем коде     
            public List<FoodCartItem> getFoodItems()
        {
            return appDBContent.foodCartItems.Where(c => c.FoodCartId == FoodCartId).Include(s => s.food).ToList();
        }                             Invalid object name 'foodCartItems

Comment: @nikitasalnikov в гитхабе обновите всё то что вы изменили. То что там было я скачал и все работает. Снова скачаю и посмотрю

Comment: @nikitasalnikov у вас Таблица foodCartItems существует в базе данных?